# Manually pushed view controller freezes app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to manually push a view controller within my iOS 8 app. I have designed it in the `Main.storyboard` and i have already attached on it an specific identifier.
The code i am using is:

```
CustomViewController *vc =
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CustomViewController"];
    vc.customField1 = self.customField1;
    vc.customField2 = self.customField2;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

but that causes the app's freeze. It does not spit out any logs or something, so I cannot understand what might be wrong.

Can you help me a bit here?

Thank in advance

Comment: Is there any code in the 'viewDidLoad' or 'awakeFromNib' (or other methods) in the new view controller that could be causing an infinite loop?

Comment: What does "freeze" mean here? What is actually happening (or not)?

Comment: @matt"freeze" here means that the app does not execute the new view controllers code, neither instantiates it neither shows it, it's just stack there.

Comment: @RoboticCat yes there is a viewDidLoad function

Comment: Is your initial view controller embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: yes, this is a tab bar application, if i understand right you're question (sorry, ios noob still)

Comment: A tab bar controller an a navigation controller are two different things. I presume you setup the storyboard; you should know whether it has a navigation controller or not.

Comment: to answer the initial question, the initial view controller is embedded in a navigation controller

Comment: By initial, do you mean the tab bar controller or the controller in the first tab? You should describe what controller you have.

Comment: i mean the controller in the first tab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67683/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-koslib).

Answer (score 2):

Do not do these two lines:

```
   vc.customField1 = self.customField1;
   vc.customField2 = self.customField2;
```

The problem here is that you're assigning one text field to *be* another text field (actually, you're making a text field reference *refer* to a completely different text field). Instead, copy the *contents* (e.g. the text) of the fields from your parent view controller to fields that already live in your new CustomViewController:

```
   vc.customField1.text = self.customField1.text;
   vc.customField2.text = self.customField2.text;
```

I'm thinking what is happening here is that the app is hanging when the new CustomViewController appears because it's trying to access fields in the now hidden / pushed-away parent view controller.

Comment: "The app is getting confused"? Really? That's a thing to say? :)

Comment: yeah yeah... I'll clean that up. I wasn't being super specific because the O.P. didn't say exactly what those outlets (or fields) actually were.

Comment: Can I try editing this for you? I think I can say it more clearly. I don't want to be rude, though, so stop me if you'd rather do it yourself.

Comment: You're a way more professional (and published!) author than I am so yeah, if you can state the point I was trying to make a little bit better, I'd love to see it.

Comment: no no, actually those fields are a string and a url. `vc.fileURL = self.fileurl; vc.currentTrack = self.currentTrack;` so there's no .text or something to pass to the new controller. So how can i pass data to the new view controller here?